# Java combo box model and get selected item

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

The code below shows a problem I'm having with combo actions. The getSelectedItem() is fired multiple times instead of just at selection. Simply loading the frame calls the method 3 times. Each click on the combo box is a call, even if its just for the dropdown and not the actual selection. Clicking inside the editable text area also triggers the getSelectedItem() method. Is there a way to filter this event?, or an alternate way to validate data on the box model level?

```
public class SSCCE {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame aframe = new JFrame();
    Combo _combo = new Combo();
    _combo.addElement("This");
    _combo.addElement("That");
    JComboBox _box = new JComboBox(new Combo());
    _box.setEditable(true);
    aframe.add(_box);
    aframe.setVisible(true);

}

static class Combo extends DefaultComboBoxModel{
    public Combo(){
    }
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        System.out.println("Get selected Item" + i);
        i++;
        return super.getSelectedItem();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There is likely a better option than overriding `getSelectedItem()`.

Comment: Where does it say it will only be called once per selection event? This is a job for an action listener, not a model override.

Answer (score 3):

See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) on how to use JComboBox, specifically the section on handling events. You should add an `ActionListener` to your combobox. It will be triggered when the user actually makes a gesture indicating that their selection is confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

You have look at [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) or [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) added to the [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Answer (score 0):

getSelectedItem() indeed fires multiple times, as well as the action event. For an editable combo box the action fires once for comboboxchanged, and once for comboboxedited. I've set up the validation that is not specific to end item in the getSelectedItem, and moved the rest into a filtered action event for comboboxchanged. I've completely ignored comboboxedited event.